# cannot mix between single row and multi-row (BULK) in INTO list.ERROR in proc

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RDBSTAGE.ATCHMNT_ERR_FILEID AUTHID CURRENT_USER
IS
  CURSOR cv_atchtab IS
    SELECT * FROM ATTACHMENT_ERROR;
  I_ATCHMNT_ERR cv_atchtab%ROWTYPE;
  V_FILE_ID VARCHAR2(40);
BEGIN
  OPEN cv_atchtab;
  LOOP
    FETCH cv_atchtab BULK COLLECT INTO I_ATCHMNT_ERR;
    EXIT WHEN cv_atchtab%NOTFOUND;
    FOR i IN 1..I_ATCHMNT_ERR.COUNT
    LOOP
      SELECT FILE_ID BULK COLLECT
      INTO V_FILE_ID
      FROM ATTACHMENT_CLAIM t1
      WHERE t1.CLAIM_TCN_ID=I_ATCHMNT_ERR(i).CLAIM_TCN_ID;
      UPDATE ATTACHMENT_ERROR
      SET FILE_ID          = V_FILE_ID
      WHERE t1.CLAIM_TCN_ID=I_ATCHMNT_ERR.CLAIM_TCN_ID;
    END LOOP;

  END LOOP;    
  CLOSE cv_atchtab;    
END;

END ATCHMNT_ERR_FILEID;

/
SHOW ERRORS
```

Procedure ATCHMNT_ERR_FILEID compiled

> Errors: check compiler log Errors for PROCEDURE
>    RDBSTAGE.ATCHMNT_ERR_FILEID:
>   LINE/COL ERROR
>
> ---
>
> 11/40 PLS-00497: cannot mix between single row and multi-row (BULK) in INTO list
>   14/5 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   14/31 PLS-00302: component 'COUNT' must be declared

Comment: For future reference please **edit your question** to include addition information or clarifications.

Comment: Is this a learning exercise, or is this for production code?

Comment: @boneist - I for one am hoping this is not for production.

Answer (score 0):

> PLS-00497: cannot mix between single row and multi-row (BULK) in INTO list

BULK COLLECT INTO is the syntax for populating a PL/SQL collection from a query. But your code is populating a scalar single row variable.

> 14/31 PLS-00302: component 'COUNT' must be declared

I_ATCHMNT_ERR.COUNT is invalid because `count()` only applies to collections I_ATCHMNT_ERR is scalar.

To fix this you need to define and use collection types. Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ATCHMNT_ERR_FILEID
IS
  CURSOR cv_atchtab IS
    SELECT * FROM ATTACHMENT_ERROR;

  type ATCHMNT_ERR_nt is table of cv_atchtab%ROWTYPE;
  I_ATCHMNT_ERR ATCHMNT_ERR_nt;

  V_FILE_ID VARCHAR2(40);
BEGIN
  OPEN cv_atchtab;
  LOOP
    FETCH cv_atchtab BULK COLLECT INTO I_ATCHMNT_ERR; -- collection type
    EXIT WHEN I_ATCHMNT_ERR.COUNT = 0; -- changed this

    FOR i IN 1..I_ATCHMNT_ERR.COUNT
    LOOP
      SELECT FILE_ID 
      INTO V_FILE_ID  -- scalar type
      FROM ATTACHMENT_CLAIM t1
      WHERE t1.CLAIM_TCN_ID = I_ATCHMNT_ERR(i).CLAIM_TCN_ID;

      UPDATE ATTACHMENT_ERROR t2 -- changed this
      SET FILE_ID = V_FILE_ID
      WHERE t2.CLAIM_TCN_ID = I_ATCHMNT_ERR(i).CLAIM_TCN_ID;  -- changed this
    END LOOP;

  END LOOP;    
  CLOSE cv_atchtab; 

END ATCHMNT_ERR_FILEID;
```

Here is [a db<>fiddle demo of the above](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=59492122bc4665d426ca5e878d058088) working against my guess of the data model.

The Oracle documentation is comprehensive, online and free. The PL/SQL Guide has a whole chapter on Collections and Records which I suggest you read. [Find it here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS005).

---

As an aside, nested loops with single row statements like this are usually a red flag in PL/SQL. They are pretty inefficient and slow. SQL is a set-based language, and we should always try to solve problems using SQL whenever possible, and ideally in one set-based statement. If this code is intended for production (rather than being a homework assignment) you should definitely consider re-writing it in a more performative fashion.

Comment: I have run the new changes but then getting below

Comment: ORA-00904 :"t1.CLAIM_TCN_ID" invalid identifier

Comment: Now getting this LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ---------------------------------------------------------------
25/21    PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements

Comment: i have using Oracle Database 12c

Comment: So in my previous version of your code I made V_FILE_ID a collection as well. But didn't change the SET clause in the UPDATE statement. That was the cause of the PLS-00642 error. I have fixed this by reverting V_FILE_ID to a scalar and removing the BULK COLLECT clause when it's populated. I didn't spot this error because my original test wasn't exactly the same as your scenario. So I have also done what you should have done and provided **a complete working test case**. Find mine on [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=59492122bc4665d426ca5e878d058088).